# Boot a Microsoft Surface directly in to User Mode?

Tags: pixelsense

We are planning to have an automated nightly restart of the Surface.  Is it possible to boot it directly into user mode?  I haven't been able to find anywhere to configure the default boot mode.

If not, can it boot into admin mode but then execute a command on startup to kick it into user mode?

Answer (score 2):

After you put it in user mode, reboots should go into user mode automatically